# Flutter Navigation on Dashboard screen for Desktop/web

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter, am try to create a Dashboard screen for my App, and am straggling with how to navigated to different screen without losing my side_menu in a mobile device this in not a problem but on a desktop and web it is. All the solution i found online user this method:-

```
onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NextScreen()),
              );
            },
```

It works but with this method am loosing the side_menu in the NextScreen and i have the recreate it in ever screen. Here is my code i hope there is a better way of doind this.

My main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Prestige Admin',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
            .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
        canvasColor: secondaryColor,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => MenuControls(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MainScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

mainscreen.dart

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: context.read<MenuControls>().scaffoldKey,
      drawer: const SideMenu(),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          // We want this side menu only for large screen
          if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
            const Expanded(
              // default flex = 1
              // and it takes 1/6 part of the screen
              child: SideMenu(),
            ),
          const Expanded(
            // It takes 5/6 part of the screen
            flex: 5,
            child: DashboardScreen(),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

side_menu.dar

```
class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideMenu({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/prestigelogo2.png"),
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Dashboard",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_dashbord.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Products",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/list.svg",
            press: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProductsScreen()),
              );
            },
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Production",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_task.svg",
            press: () {
                 Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProductionScreen()),
               },
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Documents",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_doc.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Inventory",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/inventory.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Reports",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/grid_view.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Customers & Suppliers",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_profile.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Users",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_profile.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
          DrawerListTile(
            title: "Settings",
            svgSrc: "assets/icons/menu_setting.svg",
            press: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    // For selecting those three line once press "Command+D"
    required this.title,
    required this.svgSrc,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title, svgSrc;
  final VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: press,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      leading: SvgPicture.asset(
        svgSrc,
        color: Colors.white54,
        height: 16,
      ),
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and My MenuControls.dar

```
class MenuControls extends ChangeNotifier {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> get scaffoldKey => _scaffoldKey;

  void controlMenu() {
    if (!_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
    }
  }
}
```